# What is the difference between `&str` and `&'static str` in a static or const?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust programming and learning about lifetimes.

```
const CONST_MEEP: &str = "MEEP";
const CONST_LIFETIME_MEEP: &'static str = "MEEP";
static STATIC_MEEP: &'static str = "MEEP";
static STATIC_LIFETIME_MEEP: &str = "MEEP";

fn main() {
    println!("CONST_MEEP is {}", CONST_MEEP);
    println!("CONST_LIFETIME_MEEP is {}", CONST_LIFETIME_MEEP);
    println!("STATIC_MEEP is {}", STATIC_MEEP);
    println!("STATIC_LIFETIME_MEEP is {}", STATIC_LIFETIME_MEEP);
}
```

The output:

```
CONST_MEEP is MEEP
CONST_LIFETIME_MEEP is MEEP
STATIC_MEEP is MEEP
STATIC_LIFETIME_MEEP is MEEP
```

What is the difference between `CONST_MEEP` and `CONST_LIFETIME_MEEP`? What is the difference between `STATIC_MEEP` and `STATIC_LIFETIME_MEEP`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing, there is no difference. As of [RFC 1623](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1623-static.md), references in `static` and `const` items are automatically `'static`. This took effect in [Rust 1.17](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/04/27/Rust-1.17.html).